# Can anyone identify the set these plastic flags belong to? They are mixed in with several old castle sets

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, piece-information

[image]
Flexible plastic material [image]
Two blue plastic flags (?) with “U” and Two red ones with Bulls.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! I appreciate you including high quality images in your post to make the identification easier. Just as a heads up, I did remove your "thank you" comment, as it was posted on your question rather than the answer as you likely intended.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are:

- [Plastic Flag 3 x 6 Ninja Pattern Blue](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x55&in=S)

and

- [Plastic Flag 3 x 6 Ninja Pattern Red](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x65&colorID=0&in=A)

they come from the old [Ninja](https://brickset.com/sets/subtheme-Ninja) sub-theme

one of each appears in
[4805: Ninja Knights](https://brickset.com/sets/4805-1/Ninja-Knights)
[image]